# PHP Array Sorting alphanumeric with array_multisort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I would like to use the functionality of SORT_ASC, SORT_DESC with array_multisort()

but the problem is, it sorts my array like

```
test.1
test.10
test.2
test.3
test.4
test.5
```

it should be

```
test.1
test.2
test.3
test.4 
...
test.10
```

currently using it like this

```
array_multisort(($sortc), (($sortby==='asc') ? SORT_ASC : SORT_DESC), $pool);
```

$sortc is the array I want to sort from the multi-dimensional array of $pool

I do know that natsort can do it properly, but it doesnt have the same functionality as array_multisort.

Comment: sort($myarr, SORT_NUMERIC);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use natural sort. Just add the [`SORT_NATURAL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#refsect1-function.array-multisort-parameters) flag.

```
array_multisort(($sortc), (($sortby==='asc') ? SORT_ASC : SORT_DESC), SORT_NATURAL, $pool);
```

Comment: That was worked. thank you! I didn't realize you could add multiple SORT constants to one, I knew you could do many arrays with different sorts.